# PhpMyAdmin redirection

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, webserver, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin using the apt-get command on ubuntu.
I don't see any local folder named phpmyadmin, but when I visit domain.tld/phpmyadmin, it redirects. Where is this redirection happening?

Comment: Probaly in `http.conf` or `http-vhosts.conf` using an `Alias` directive. Search Apache's `conf` dir for "phpMyAdmin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection is configured in  /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf and phpmyadmin directoriy itself resides in /var/lib directory.

You can also check all package files by:

```
dpkg -L phpmyadmin
```

Comment: The problem is I already deleted phpMyAdmin but still see the redirection happening. There is no phpmyadmin.conf or /var/lib/phpmyadmin.

Comment: Did you try to run sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload ? ;) As I've stated in the answer, phpmyadmin.conf is located in /etc/apache2/conf.d folder, not in /var/lib/phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the apt-get version of phpmyadmin actually adding the mapping of phmyadmin to the configuration for the enabled websites.

Check out /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/